# Field values missing from quantity symbology options in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, fields-attributes, choropleth

I am using ArcMap.

I joined table data to the latest TIGERLine tract shapefile for my county and exported the data. When I attempt to create a choropleth/thematic map, many of the fields in the table are not visible/options to choose from the Value Field in the Quantities symbology. E.G. I cannot find/choose 2015 Median Income as a value for a graduated color map.

[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot for your table after joining and export? does it still have your desired field (2015 median income)?

Comment: The Value Field in symbology requires Numeric field types.  From the look of your table these fields are all Text field types (based solely on the fact they are all displayed left-aligned).  Create a new Numeric field and copy the values you need to it

Comment: I created a new [type=short] field for each [type=string] field to be converted. I attempted to create new numeric values for each new field using the Field Calcuator. I set the new field equal to the string (following the https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002287 article), but got the following message when I hit 'Ok.'

"The calculated value is invalid for the row with ObjectID = 1. For example, the calculated value may be too large for the field or you may be trying to add a string to a number field. This row will not be updated.

Comment: @RyanStephenson If your values without decimal points, so choose (Long integer), if they are with decimal points, then choose (double or float). please have a look over the different type in this [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/arcgis-field-data-types.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Value Field in symbology requires Numeric field types, and my table fields are all Text type fields.  Creating a new field of types Short, Long, Float or Double will fix the problem, but each are appropriate for different number types i.e. integers, decimals. Opening the Field Calculator on the newly created number field, and clicking on the text field that the new number field is to represent, moving it into the dialog box sets the operation to be 'calculated.' TargetName_number = TargetName_string. Clicking 'OK' calculates all fields.